# The Extension for RFCOMM(bluetooth) and WIFI

Tags: security

i want to block bluetooth rfcomm using EDR. i can block application using the file extensions for eg : exe or any type of extensions as well as services. I thought like bluetooth also have extension and it services unfortunitly the bluetooth doesn't have extension and services so i searched with google i have finds so extensions like .sys for bluetooth through this option i can't block those connectivity. Anyone can please share the details for the same. This rfcomm is new for me if you know the ans please share with me.

you can tell like rf is remote frequency there is no need softwares for send the frequency but here if there is no software whenever the bluetooth is sending file are initating the connection i have to create one service or services the taskmanager should refelect the service but there is no services. Waiting for your answer for securing the organization.

i tried to find the extension and its services. I can't find those things

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.